# Reusing Atheros ar5bxb63 mini PCI-E WLAN Card

Tags: wireless-networking

I took apart an old and broken laptop to see what components could be reused, and found an `Atheros ar5bxb63 mini PCI-E WLAN Card`. I was wondering what it would take to reuse it for a tower pc? Would it be very complicated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory all you needs is a PCIe to  mini PCIe adapter.

[image]

However for a wireless card you might want to have some antennas. Usually those are build into the laptop frame and or the frame of the laptops screen. Without those reception might be poor. Especially if you have a sturdy steel desktop case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll give it a go as soon as I have some time ;)